# Changing font color in link

Tags: html, fonts, youtube

I must first advise that I am new to coding. Please be gentle. I am attempting to change the color of the font in a link to an embedded video contained in an eBay listing. This code was generated by the "embed" feature of YouTube, and I simply pasted it into the html of the item description. I cannot get the color of the font to change when changing the color code. It always stays the same. I can change the font size, though. Why does this work and not color changes? Here is the line of code for the embedded video I am working with. Any help is appreciated.
   This is an edit after I posted the question. I pasted the code into my question but it shows up as my link. I do not know how to make the actual code appear in my query without showing up as the resulting link.

***[For a video click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=482ywzMbVfE)***

Comment: Maybe a specificity problem. Have a look at this great article: https://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/. And please provide some code. It's easier to understand your problem and what you're trying to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tag `<font color="#000000">` and use inline CSS to change the color, like this

```
<b>
  <font face="Verdana" size="12">
   <i>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=482ywzMbVfE" style="color: #000000">For a video click here</a>
   </i>
   </font>
</b>
```

Notice the `style="color: #000000"` attribute added to the `<a>` tag.

---

You can also use inline CSS to change the font and make it italics. Just remove the tags `<font face="Verdana" size="12">`, `<i>` an use the `font-family` and `font-style` CSS properties like this,

```
<b>
 <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=482ywzMbVfE" style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40px; font-style: italic;">For a video click here</a>
</b>
```

Notice the `style="color: #000000; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 40px; font-style: italic;"` attribute added to the `<a>` tag.

Hope this helps :)